# Double integral with function and sampled data Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for a way to perform double integration on sampled data using numpy trapz or a similar function from the scipy stack.

In particular, I would like to calculate function:

[image: Equation]

where `f(x',y')` is the sampled array and `F(x, y)` is an array of the same dimension.

This is my attempt, which gives incorrect results:

```
def integrate_2D(f, x, y):
    def integral(f, x, y, x0, y0):
        F_i = np.trapz(np.trapz(np.arcsinh(1/np.sqrt((x-x0+0.01)**2+(y-y0+0.01)**2)) * f, x), y)
        return F_i
    sigma = 1.0
    F = [[integral(f, x, y, x0, y0) for x0 in x] for y0 in y]
    return F

xlin = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
ylin = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xlin, ylin)

f = 1.0 * np.exp(-((X - 8.)**2 + (Y - 8)**2)/(8.0))
f += 0.5 * np.exp(-((X - 1)**2 + (Y - 9)**2)/(10.0))

F = integrate_2D(f, xlin, ylin)
```

The output array seems to be oriented towards the diagonal of the resulting grid, while it should rather return an array that looks like blurred input array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see what you're trying to do, but the nesting is hiding the logic.  Try something like this,

```
def int_2D( x, y, xlo=0.0, xhi=10.0, ylo=0.0, yhi=10.0, Nx=100, Ny=100 ):

    # construct f(x,y) for given limits
    #-----------------------------------
    xlin = np.linspace(xlo, xhi, Nx)
    ylin = np.linspace(ylo, yhi, Ny)
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(xlin, ylin)

    f = 1.0 * np.exp(-((X - 8.)**2 + (Y - 8)**2)/(8.0))
    f += 0.5 * np.exp(-((X - 1)**2 + (Y - 9)**2)/(10.0))

    # construct 2-D integrand
    #-----------------------------------
    m = np.sqrt( (x - X)**2 + (y - Y)**2 )
    y = 1.0 / np.arcsinh( m ) * f

    # do a 1-D integral over every row
    #-----------------------------------
    I = np.zeros( Ny )
    for i in range(Ny):
        I[i] = np.trapz( y[i,:], xlin )

    # then an integral over the result
    #-----------------------------------    
    F = np.trapz( I, ylin )

    return F
```

Comment: Yeah! That's it. I wish I could add some images already to show what it looks like!