# How to do bounds to solve double integral for data arrays? Python

Tags: python, numpy, integral

[Double integral with function and sampled data Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875722/double-integral-with-function-and-sampled-data-python)

Refer to this question, similarly, I need to solve a double integral for a sampled data which I don't know the function that generates it. I have understood how this answer does to solve such problem.

However, in my case the data is above a certain region which varies depending on an extra parameter that I also have as an array. To make a case, I now assume it is bounded by a circular region.

[image]

a,b and r are constant, d is the parameter list. I want a result of list to have same length of d. And for some reason, I want to keep it in Cartesian coordinate system.

The data always cover the moving region. I was thinking to cut the data in order to just keep the part in the region and then use the solution from the question. I imagine it may lead to big error if I restrict the data region always (smaller than)/in the bound.

Is there a better function in numpy package to solve definite double integral for data array in stead of using np.trapz?

Answer (score 1):

The code below uses [`nquad()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html#scipy.integrate.nquad) from [scipy library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html#module-scipy.integrate) and is based on equation in question and examples [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html). The `result` and `abserr` (absolute error) are stored in a dataframe.

**Import libraries**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
```

**Set values for global variables**

```
a = 0
b = 10
r = 10
d_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

**Define functions**

```
def f(x, y):
    return x*y

def bounds_y():
    return [a, b]

def bounds_x(y):
    return [0, np.sqrt(r**2 - (y-d)**2)]
```

**Iterate over values in 'd'**

```
temp = []
for i in d_list:
    d = i # re-set global value of 'd'
    temp.append(integrate.nquad(f, [bounds_x, bounds_y]))
```

**Save result and error values in a dataframe**

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(temp, columns=['result', 'abserr'])
temp
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I think this only applies to a defined function but I am looking to find the volume under a set of data points.